# File is not defined in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cloud9

I'm writing a code in JavaScript the opens a file then read it:

```
var txtFile = "/dataset/happy.txt";
var fileH = new File(txtFile);
var fileS = new File("/dataset/sad.txt");
var fileA = new File("/dataset/angry.txt");
var fileSC = new File("/dataset/scared.txt");
var fileSU = new File("/dataset/suprised.txt");

fileH.open("r"); // open file with read access
```

But I get (ReferenceError: File is not defined) error
What's the problem?

Thank you :)

Comment: Which browser are you working on? Read the supported browser list: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File

Comment: What ever browser/environment you're working with doesn't support the Feile API

Comment: @Raptor I'm working on Cloud9 and I tried both chrom and edge

Comment: Where did you read about a `File` type that would work this way?

Comment: @Ryan This is what I found when I searched Google. Also: https://gist.github.com/Arahnoid/9925725

Comment: That appears to be for Photoshop automation. Not going to work in Node.js/browser/anything else.

Comment: @Ryan So What's the solution?

Comment: Look up documentation appropriate to the platform you want to use. Are you trying to write a Node.js project?

Comment: @Ryan Yes exactly

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback but you should probably start with a Node.js tutorial, or by learning JavaScript without the Node parts first.